# How to get and use the address of constant value without declaring a variable to it?

Tags: c++, file, constants

I am trying to write/modify a value into a File with its File Descriptor. I am using a write() function which has the prototype as ->
`write(file_descriptor, address_of_values_to_be_written, no_of_bytes_to_be_written);`
At some point, I need to write a value into File. **I don't want to declare a pointer or a variable to it.** What is the format to specify that value at address part of the prototype? Can we do something like this->
`write(fd, &(200), sizeof(int));`

Thanks:)

Comment: *I don't want to declare a pointer or a variable to it.* Why?

Comment: You can't get the address of an integer literal, you need to store it in a variable.

Comment: Also, never hard-code sizes. If you need the size of an `int` then use `sizeof(int)`. Or if you have an `int` variable (lets call it `value`) then you can do `sizeof value`.

Comment: Although I would not recommend doing this, `&static_cast<const int&>(200)` technically works without any variable (though with a temporary object).

Comment: I honestly can't remember if compound literals are supported in C++.  If they are, `write(fd, (int[]){200}, sizeof(int))` would probably do what you want.

Comment: @WhozCraig They are not.

Comment: @walnut lame. that would have been a handy solution to what is no-doubt an entirely contrived "problem".

Comment: @GauravSehgal There are many places in the entire code where I have to do this. So declaring temporary variables for all of them isn't the best idea.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am actually working on a driver file, which is always divided in chunks of 4 bytes, so only I have directly used the literal like that.

Answer (score 3):

A good solution would be a wrapper (either a lambda or a full function):

```
auto write_int(int fd, int n) { return write(fd, &n, sizeof n); }
```

which you can use as:

```
write_int(fd, 200);
```

---

You could also use helper classes to enable syntax like `write(fd, addressable_int(200), sizeof 200)`,  or `write(fd, &200_a, sizeof 200)`  but people would wonder what you were smoking.

Comment: To be honest, I'm already wondering what the OP is smoking.   A "requirement" to pass the address for a value without declaring "a pointer or variable to it" is specious, at best.

Comment: @Peter I guess they just want to save some keystrokes in writing the int to the file

Comment: @M.M Actually the code is very huge and a combination of 9 files, out of which I am performing these file operations only in one file and some times we need to write a constant directly into that location. so based on this I am treating creating and using a temporary variable always is not a proper way to do so.